# SOAP/XML to JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, soap, xml-parsing

I wish to extract the ItemName and Value pairs from the SOAP/XML string below. I have wrecked my head going through the web trying out various proper ways to do this. I have given up and just want to parse the data as a string. I have looked at XSLT but I need to associate the SOAP data with some more human readable data so having it all in a JavaScript array would be better for me.

[Chunk of my horrible original JavaScript code removed and replaced with good code.]

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Body>
<ReadResponse xmlns="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/">
<ReadResult RcvTime="2012-05-02T13:25:39.484+01:00" ReplyTime="2012-05-02T13:25:39.484+01:00" RevisedLocaleID="en" ServerState="running">    </ReadResult>
<RItemList>
<Items ItemName="_System._DateTime">
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2012-05-02T12:25:38.000+01:00</Value>
    <Quality></Quality>
</Items>
<Items ItemName="_System._ProjectTitle">
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Job2663</Value>
    <Quality></Quality>
</Items>
</RItemList>
</ReadResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

//Edited below to include correct code based on Rocket's solution below.
$(soap).find('Items').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('ItemName'), ':', $('Value', this).html());
});
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use jQuery?  jQuery can parse the XML for you, and you can traverse it using jQuery methods.

```
$(soap).find('Items').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('ItemName'), $('Value', this).attr('xsi:type'));
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/JMTHs/

Comment: Thanks, Rocket. Fantastic. We're nearly there. We want to return ["_System._DateTime", "2012-05-02T12:25:38.000+01:00"], ["_System._ProjectTitle", 'Job2663']. How do I retrieve the item between the value /value tags?

Comment: Rocket, thanks again for the pointer. I figured out the rest (all new stuff to me). I've edited the original post for clarity.